# Camera's background color with 32-bits per channel

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl

I need the Unity's `Camera.Render()` to generate a specific rendering of a mesh - the output texture has to be with format `GraphicsFormat.R32G32B32A32_UInt`, i.e. 32 bits per **channel** and thus 128 bits per pixel. The background of the rendering should be a specific 128 bit color as well, however I can only set `Camera.backgroundColor` with classes `Color` and `Color32`, that store at most 8 bits per channel.

I have a fallback idea how to overcome this - by rendering a quad with a shader that outputs a constant 128 bit color, but I would like to first find out if it's possible with plain `Camera.backgroundColor` or some raw OpenGL command.

Before I used Unity, I had known for sure that you can call OpenGL command `glClearColor()` with passing 32-bit values per channel, so it's really puzzling why Unity can't support it as well.

Please, could you suggest a more or less conventional way for Unity to pass a 128 bit clear color, or how can I call a raw OpenGL command with `Camera.Render()` to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the (platform-independent) shader solution as even though the Color (not Color32) struct consists of a float for each channel and thus 4 byte per channel, it still is a floating point number.

You could try the following:

- Enable HDR in your Project Settings/Graphics
- Enable HDR on your Camera
- Set the `Camera.backgroundColor` inside a script with the Color struct (`new Color()`) even if the r,g,b,a values are way above 1.0 .

The HDR colors are handled with only 16 bits though, so it might still not be the correct clear color for the texture. Then you'd need to use the custom shader with a constant color solution. What is your specific background color value exactly?

Edit to comment:
After some research, your idea of using a custom shader (or even a compute shader) seems to be the best route as there seems to be no way to set 128bit (uint) colors to Unity's built-in variables like `Camera.backgroundColor`. I tested it for the value 250 (hex FAFAFAFA), the resulting int in base 10 would be 4210752250, as float you lose precision on the last 3 digits and get 4210752000.

At least inside a shader, you can work with `uint4` like `uint4 bgcolor = uint4(250, 250, 250, 250)` or set it from C# via a uniform. There is also the [StructuredBuffer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ComputeBuffer.html) for custom structs inside a shader if you want to transfer a lot of colors (e.g. for different states).

You'd also need to set your color space to linear in the project settings.

Comment: The background color varies, but simply speaking, the `R32G32B32A32_UInt` texture consists of 16 bytes, and I need to set all bytes to the same integer value, e.g. 250. The texture is then used for neural networks, so the value for all 16 bytes **must** be that exact integer value

Comment: Ah I see! Then you definitely have the most control with a custom shader (or even a compute shader) and maybe a StructuredBuffer<uint> for the different possible colors. To set and read the specific bytes of each uint you could work with bitwise logic. I'll edit my answer accordingly.